# Are we compromising performance for achieving code readability when using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I have tried checking LINQ performance against conventional brute-force search and it seems LINQ is much slower than the brute force approach and using Contains method takes even longer!

The following is my code:

```
class Program
{
  int[] array;
  public Program(int size)
  {
     array = new int[size];
     for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
     {
        array[i] = size - i;
     }
  }
  public void BruteForceSearch(int toBeSearched)
  {
     foreach (int i in array)
     {
        if (i == toBeSearched)
        {
           return;
        }
     }
  }
  public void SearchViaContainsMethod(int toBeSearched)
  {
     if (array.Contains(toBeSearched)) { return; }
  }
  public void SearchViaLINQ(int toBeSearched)
  {
     var x = from a in array
             where a == toBeSearched
             select a;
  }
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
     Program p = new Program(100000);
     using (new OperationTimer("BruteForceSearch"))
     {
        p.BruteForceSearch(0);
     }
     using (new OperationTimer("SearchViaContainsMethod"))
     {
        p.SearchViaContainsMethod(0);
     }
     using (new OperationTimer("SearchViaLINQ"))
     {
        p.SearchViaLINQ(0);
     }
     Console.Read();
  }



class OperationTimer : IDisposable
{
  private Stopwatch m_stopwatch;
  private String m_text;

  public OperationTimer(String text)
  {
     m_text = text;
     m_stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
  }

  public void Dispose()
  {
     Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}",
        (m_stopwatch.Elapsed), m_text);
  }
}
```

Output:

00:00:00.0009032 BruteForceSearch
00:00:00.0068469 SearchViaContainsMethod
00:00:00.0032512 SearchViaLINQ

I can understand the time taken is very low for everything and with the current processor's speed using the LINQ may not create memory overhead.

I would like to know, when processing a huge set of data, will the speed will go exponentially higher and we really have to compromise on the speed for code-readability?

Please help understanding this.

(Courtesy: OperationTimer type was taken from [CLR Via C#](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&ved=0CDgQFjAC&url=http://www.amazon.com/CLR-via-Microsoft-Developer-Reference/dp/0735667454&ei=gFteUsLRMoPYrQfBtYC4CA&usg=AFQjCNFVR3WlKP13y-plixegtOF0wL2_WQ&sig2=NjM5DBKCMfvRHqQvdR0ruQ&bvm=bv.54176721,d.bmk) by Jeffery Ritcher.

Comment: Have you tried switching the operations? Maybe the disposing is delaying some calculations.

Comment: Yes it's more expensive to use LINQ. The value is in readability and maintainability.  In most real working environments, LINQ is great as it'll increase your output, and the performance difference is neglible. Discussions like these are largely academic except for extreme or specific circumstances.

Comment: Your SearchViaLINQ method does not even perform the search. Not that it matters. What is wrong here is your benchmark. Read this: http://tech.pro/blog/1293/c-performance-benchmark-mistakes-part-one

Comment: @JeroenVannevel
I did and got similar results:

00:00:00.0047292 SearchViaContainsMethod

00:00:00.0039596 SearchViaLINQ

00:00:00.0008588 BruteForceSearch

Comment: @KrisVandermotten additionally, the linq expression (when it is enumerated) will be an exhaustive search via `Where()` while the others stop upon finding the item.  `.First()` would be more appropriate.

Comment: You could use a `HashSet<int>` instead. `var lookup = new HashSet<int>(array);`. This is much faster : `if(lookup.Contains(0)){}`. So if the array cannot contain duplicates or they don't matter at all use a set in the first place. Otherwise you could hold it beside the array even if it costs memory. Note that you can use `HashSet.Add` to check if it contains and add it in one step.

Comment: You are doing it wrong. Read about linq deferred execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite that simple; also the original example doesn't actually find anything in the LINQ statement - just builds the expression tree; to actually locate the element you'd need to realise the linq expression; or change it to something like

```
var rv = array.SingleOrDefault(xx=>xx == toBeSearched);
```

Don't forget that you need to do the whole thing twice on the same class as there are startup overheads; doing this gives us

```
00:00:00.0001726 BruteForceSearch
00:00:00.0001774 SearchViaContainsMethod
00:00:00.0011443 SearchViaLINQ

00:00:00.0000009 BruteForceSearch
00:00:00.0000881 SearchViaContainsMethod
00:00:00.0009255 SearchViaLINQ
```

So; as with all things performance profiling real world situations is the only valid way to optimise. It's one of the hardest things to get right from the beginning and it gets (slightly) easier with experience.

Comment: SearchViaLinq is doing nothing. Result Enumerator is not consumed

Comment: yeah I just noticed that; effectively the benchmark is tested the expression build of a LINQ statement. I Changed it to array.SingleOrDefault(xx=>xx == toBeSearched); and linq is much slower...

Comment: yes indeed!

00:00:00.0041266 SearchViaContainsMethod
00:00:00.0032913 SearchViaLINQ
00:00:00.0007066 BruteForceSearch
00:00:00.0001127 SearchViaContainsMethod
00:00:00.0000046 SearchViaLINQ
00:00:00.0005790 BruteForceSearch

Answer (score 4):

Yes, we are doing exactly that: choosing code readability over performance. But in the vast majority of cases, it's really better to have the improved code readability. If you're working with very limited memory or CPU, or in a very performance-sensitive environment, it might be an issue. But if you were in such an environment, you shouldn't have chosen a high-level language/platform like C#/.NET.

If you profile your application and find that the overhead of LINQ is adding a significant amount of time for some particular operation, then you can rewrite it to be more efficient. To worry about it before that point is just [premature micro-optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization), and does more harm than good.

Answer (score 3):

Usually Linq will be slower for the common sense reason that is an implementation on top of IEnumerable and that is just an abstraction. Any algorithm with intimate knowledge of the data structures used "can" be faster that any abstracted implementation.

Now your specific benchmark is not correct because the implementations are not equivalent:

- the linq one should use Any extension method to be sure you break the iteration on the first match as you do with the other 2
- the linq method seems to not execute anyway as you are not enumerating the results at all so that makes me very suspicious about the stuff you actually measured

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are, LINQ is not magic, it's an high-level instruction to the compiler.

Comment: Linq is not magic, yeah, but I find deferred execution magic :)